# What to do with dried vegetables that feel like a chewing gum?

Tags: vegetables, drying

Several months ago I dried some vegetables, mainly cabbage and carrot. I cut them to thin small slices using a slicer, dried them in about 50 C, and stored in glass jars.

Now, I opened the jars and tried eating them. Their look and taste is OK, but their texture has become hard and chewy, like a chewing gum. When I eat them, I need to chew them for a very long time before I can swallow.

What can I do with these vegetables?

Comment: How did you dry them (e.g. what size of pieces) & how are you eating / preparing them?

Comment: Definitely sounds like either the drying process or the storage process has gone wrong. I think most likely the storage but we will need to know a little more in order to help you.

Comment: Rehydrate them :)

Answer (score 4):

Of course they will be the texture of thinly sliced rubber tires when eaten raw.

What you want to do is rehydrate them. Probably the easiest way would be adding them to a stew and simmer / boil them until the entire dish is done. You will need some extra water, though.

You could also try soaking them in water over night like one does for dried fruit / muesli, then drain and use them.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for the carrot. However, the cabbage still feels like rubber tire even after many hours in water...

Comment: Did you cook or just soak the cabbage? I would expect it to be edible when stewed (perhaps after a good soaking).

Comment: maybe this is why people don't commonly dehydrate cabbage.

Comment: @rumtscho : yes, but people also used to have cold cellers, so they didn't need to.  (and they could've stored carrots in there, too)  Personally, I think sauerkraut is the way to go for putting up surplus cabbage.